# Why does using an oscillator in the Web Audio API always leak memory in Chrome? bug?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I was under the impression that I only needed to `stop` the node, and remove all references to it.

The following code leaks memory in Chrome:

```
const context = new AudioContext();
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    const node = context.createOscillator();
    node.start();
    node.stop();
}
```

However, it doesn't leak in Firefox.

Is there something wrong with my code, or is it just a bug in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Chrome.  Please file a bug at crbug.com/new.

Comment: [I've just created the issue here.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=789035). Thanks for the bug report link.